# setting guifont in .vimrc does not work Windows 11

Tags: windows, vim, startup, startupscript

Using GVIM version 9 on Windows 11 23H2, I use Edit > Select Font to choose Lucida Console size 12 and it works as expected.  When I type `:set guifont?` I see

```
set guifont=Lucida_Console:h12:cANSI:qDRAFT
```

If I start gvim and use the command line instead, it also works:

```
:set guifont=Lucida_Console:h12:cANSI:qDRAFT
```

I want this for every session. I have tried several things:

1. put the line into `.gvimrc`:

   ```
   set guifont=Lucida_Console:h12:cANSI:qDRAFT
   ```
2. put it into `.vimrc` with test for `gui_running`:

   ```
   if has('gui_running')
       set guifont=Lucida_Console:h12
   endif
   ```
3. put the line into a `.vimrc` that contains other configurations that do work, so I know the `.vimrc` is being read
4. tried it with `Consolas` instead of `Lucida_Console`

In every case, I get only the standard tiny font.

How can I make this work? Thanks.

PS I have googled and searched stackoverflow without finding an answer.

Comment: `:verbose set guifont?` to find out where the font was (re)set.

Answer (score -1):

In windows the vimrc file for GVIM is called **_vimrc** and must be either in the directory **C:\Users\UserName** or in \ **C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim**.

Comment: My impression was that it could be anywhere so long as you set the HOME environment variable to the directory path that has it. I have it on my D: drive instead and am able to edit without admin rights, and I know the file is being processed.